# Types in Angular/Typescript interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, polymorphism, extending

In my app I have `BaseObjectInterface` and I extend it in many interfaces like `AObjInterface`, `BObjInterface`, ect.
Then I have parent interface that has array of `BaseObjectInterface` in it. I want it to accept all classes that extend base one. For example `AObjInterface`, `BObjInterface`, etc. Sadly it doesn't work that way. Can I do it any other way than explicitly listing all types?

What I have:
`list: Array<BaseObjectInterface>`

What I don't want:
`list: Array<AObjInterface|BObjInterface>`

What I want put in that list:
`[ New BaseObjectInterface(), new AObjInterface(), new BObjInterface()]`

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, BaseObjectInterface is a parent of AObjInterface and BObjInterface, then the type can be just `Array<BaseObjectInterface>`. [TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPICMBWECYAkuNPEsgN4C%20AsAFCiSyIoCCe%20ZrlKEAB6QQAEwxpMOAkVLk2VOkxYV2abr1VUhI8ZKzdZmhSiWMmCAPYgMYZHChQ4ATwBcyDo5cAedAZnExvwAfMgAvMgA2nT2En7ShIHy-AA0NLSxHhrJ7GkxmOoEQewAugDcTEA)

Comment: I'm having some problem when reciving object from http request and casting them to that Interface, as well as using BaseObjectInterface<T> and then putting any of extending object into it. But still thanks for Playground example